# Visual Web Developer - Is it a mistake to use a capital letter when naming folders?

Tags: asp.net, xhtml, visual-web-developer-2010

I keep reading how xhtml and other languages alike don't like CAPITAL letters.  This may seem like a rudimentary question, but let's say you named a page, for instance:

```
Contact.aspx
```

instead of:

```
contact.aspx
```

Does it matter?  If it does matter, could I simply just rename the file, and any hyperlinks that point to it?

Thanks!

Jason Weber

Comment: In IIS it doesn't matter as it is case-insensitive. For Apache and other web servers, the path can be case sensitive (unless you configure it otherwise), so Index.html could be different to index.html, for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does it matter?

If you host your application in IIS under Windows it doesn't matter as contrary to *nix systems, filenames are not case sensitive on Windows. You could leave the filename with a capital letter and have hyperlinks point to a full lowercase url (recommended) and still execute the same page.

Comment: +1. I don't know what it is though, but I hate seeing uppercase filenames in my web solutions. Just one of those things ;-)

Comment: Thank you for that information, Darin.  That question has always bothered me, but I've never asked it.  I appreciate you taking the time to respond!